# Using stainless steel utensiles on aluminum

Tags: baking, roasting

I roast vegetables in aluminum baking pan.
To remove these, as they do get crispy, I use stainless steel spatula.

I have noticed slight scratches on the baking pan.

1. Will this affect baking in the baking pan?
2. Does this matter other than esthetics?